# What would be a good approach for several Silverlight applications with common controls?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, inheritance, base-class

I'm pretty new to Silverlight and have to code several SL applications which will share many things.

I plan to put all common C# code in a separated assembly but I'm really annoyed about the XAML part.

All my applications will have some common controls:

- a menu bar at the top,
- a toolbar at the top,
- a status bar at the bottom,
- a panel on the left.

I searched the web for hints and discovers that XAML code cannot be inherited.

So I thought about creating a big custom control containing my common controls and then adding it on the main page of all my applications but that doesn't seem to be the right way.

What's the best practice, here?

Any help appreciated,

**EDIT:** What I'd like to get here, is something I already did with WinForms. I created a "base" WinForm and put some controls on it. Then, when I created new WinForms which inherited this "base" WinForm, they had all the basic controls. I didn't have to use any custom control.

But I understand that Silverlight is not WinForm and what I want might not be feasible this way (or at all?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the route you want to take, whether you want to make one resources file with some templates etc, which is copied/linked into each application seperately, or use something included in a common DLL.

If you want to do the latter, here's one approach. Subclass `ContentControl` to define your common layout in its control template (you can do this all in XAML), including a binding to its Content in the appropriate place:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="MyLibrary.MyLayoutControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            <!-- this could be a layout grid with various other controls in it -->
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Then use it in your application root control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InCustomControlTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyLibrary;assembly=MyLibrary">

    <c:MyLayoutControl>
        <Button Content="Hi I am a button" />
    </c:MyLayoutControl>
</UserControl>
```

If you want to do something more sophisticated, you should make a custom control; though in most cases you may instead be able to get away with a few UserControls for various components (eg your status bar) that you drop into the right place.

Comment: You pretty much saved my life. ;o)
Indeed, what I wanted was something in a common DLL and your solution seems to do the trick.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is no big problem putting xaml resources in library projects. 
When referencing resourcedictionaries from other projects, be sure to include the assembly name.</s>
Also there is inheritance on templates, where you can put `BasedOn` attribute.

Edit: well, looking at the project we worked on some time ago, I now remember we actually had problems with it and had the xaml resources copied to each project... I forgot =) 
I think it worked but brought some problems here and there. Maybe add the xaml files as links?

Personally I would also not create to many controls, rather have templates for most stuff. If you have controls, better write them in c# only with usage of templates, preventing xaml with code behinds. Just my personal experience, might not be the common guideline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer bur I'm not sure I fully understand it. If I define controls in C# + templates, I still have to add them on all my pages, right? I'll edit my question to try a better explanation of what I'd like to achieve.